# nth-of-type does not work properly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following code.

```css
div img:nth-of-type(2n) {
    float: left;
}

div img:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
</div>
```

I need to set the float:left for even images and float:right for odd. But in both cases, the second css-rule is triggered. Help me please.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using nth-of-type(odd) and nth-of-type(even)?

Comment: `div img:nth-of-type(2n)` means that select those `img` elements which are 2th,4th,6th... child of their parent , which in this case is `p` and child or grandchild of `div` and as `img` is always the 1st and only child of `p`,so only the second rule is applied

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `:nth-of-type` selector on `p` tag.

Problem here is that the paragraph element is the immediate children of div. The image is nested inside a paragraph tag and not the immediate children of div. So it will not take div as its parent.

---

**v1 of the question**

```css
div p:nth-of-type(2n) img { /* Select all even */
  float: left;
}
div p:nth-of-type(2n+1) img { /* Select all odd */
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>...</p>
  ...
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
  </p>
  ...
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
  </p>
  ...
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
  </p>
  ...
</div>
```

---

**v2 of the question**

```css
div p:nth-of-type(4n+2) img { /* Select 2,6,10 */
  float: left;
}
div p:nth-of-type(4n) img { /* Select 4,8 */
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="1">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="2">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="3">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="1">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="2">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="3">
  </p>
  <p>Some random text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Properties must act only on the images, because between them may be `p` with any other text. In your case, the code only works if the pictures are in a row.

Comment: In this answer, the property will act only on the images. It does not target `p` but `img` inside `p`. I am not sure what you meant by `row` here. Check this out: http://nthmaster.com/

Comment: Compare these two versions:
1. http://jsfiddle.net/L7x1t791/4/ - It works properly
2. http://jsfiddle.net/L7x1t791/5/ - it does not work properly

Comment: No, `:nth-*` don't work that way. Check my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/L7x1t791/7/ You will need to update your code according to the HTML code.

Comment: The problem is that I do not write code in `div`, it is generated from the text editor in the admin panel, so the number of tags `p` between paragraphs with image can be various. Probably I need to look the other way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, try with jQuery. Lots of hacks can be done with it. CSS3 is limited for selection compared to jQuery in situations like these.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
div img:nth-of-type(odd) {
    float: left;
}

div img:nth-of-type(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will not work: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/kf4um7y4/ and 2n, 2n+1 are equivalent to even and odd.